# Extra bytes using FileStream (or so it seems)

Tags: c#, filestream

I am writing some JSON directly to a file, which is then read at a later date. The JSON is then deserialized using newton into an object.

I was initially do the writing like so and it was working fine:

```
using (var sw = File.CreateText(jsonFile))
{
    sw.Write(content);
}
```

I then ran into a race condition and I was told to go this route instead

```
using (var fs = new FileStream(jsonFile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Write,
    FileShare.ReadWrite))
{
    using (var sr = new StreamWriter(fs))
    {
        sr.Write(content);
    }
}
```

But when deserializing the JSON, I got this this message

> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: Additional text encountered after finished reading JSON content: u. Path ''

When I added encoding to the `StreamWriter` (UTF8), I got the same message but a different character.

So as a suggestion from a comment I tried this for the streamwriter for the encoding to remove the BOM

```
var utf8WithoutBom = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding(false);
```

Then added it to the streamwriter. The same error was returned but this time the character was blank.

Using jsonlint the JSON (content) that was written validates correctly using both methods above.

Does anyone know why the second method (using `FileStream`) doesn't work? And if so, do you have a suggestion on what I should do instead?

Comment: can edit once again and show us jsonFile

Comment: @SunilDhappadhule the JSON is valid json in both cases. Dropping it into jslint validates both regardless of which method was used. The additional text was not visible in the file.

Comment: Perhaps your "race issue" may have an influence.  Try placing a `lock` around the writing to the file.

Comment: The extra byte might be the BOM character, save your file as UTF-8 without BOM and see if you can read the json.

Comment: @AndréSanson I did try the UTF8 on the streamwriter but it returned the same exception but just a different character. I'll update the question with that.

Comment: @MicahMontoya the JSON string is obviously *not* valid, which is why you get that error. StreamReader and StreamWriter use UTF8 by default, so Unicode isn't an issue. `File.WriteAllText` and `File.ReadAllText` also use UTF8 by default

Comment: @AndréSanson both StreamReader and StreamWriter use the same defaults - [UTF8 with BOM detection](https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/mscorlib/system/io/streamreader.cs#L134)

Comment: I think to solve this you are going to show the contents of `content` and the two files. Do you have Visual Studio? If you do, you when you open the file in the open file dialog select the dropdown next to the open button. That allows you to "Open with..." Select Binary Editor to show what the byte codes are in the file. Then check the differences. It might give you a clue.

Comment: @MicahMontoya the error doesn't complain about the encoding or BOM anyway. It complains that *something* was found after the end of the JSON payload. It even points to the offending content and location. It's a `u`. The location is in the rest of the error message. The actual message should be something like `Additional text encountered after finished reading JSON content: u. Path '', line 1, position 154.`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos can you elaborate on why then using method 1 above works fine and method 2 doesnt for the same content?

Comment: @MicahMontoya your second snippet is no different than the first anyway because [File.CreateText](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/file.cs,55) simply calls `return new StreamWriter(path,true);`. That `true` means *append* though - are you appending JSON strings into the *same* file?

Comment: @MicahMontoya I just posted a link to the source code that shows they are the *same*. Either the string *isn't* valid JSON, and the error points exactly where the problem is, or your code ends up ovewriting parts of the same file. In any case, you'll have to check the file's contents

Comment: Isn't *FileShare.ReadWrite* a bad idea in this case.  You are saying that another process can open the file and write to it while you are doing the same thing.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas maybe so but this is the only process that writes to the file.

Comment: FileShare.ReadWrite is not correct.  It allows two threads/programs to write to the file at the same time.  The result is a random jumble of their output that nobody can understand.  You need to debug the code to find the threading bug instead of trying to work around it.

Comment: FileMode.Open does not erase existing file content. So if the new string is shorter than the existing file contents, you will have leftover bytes in the file, and those leftover bytes will probably trigger parser errors.